# How to determine overall CPU Usage in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I'm working on developing a distributed network program that needs to be able to determine how active a computer is.

I've found the following example at https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/balance-cpu-1-0 that I believe will give me what I want.

```
SYSTEM_INFO info = { 0 };
::GetSystemInfo(&info);

CAtlArray<ULONG64> procs;
VERIFY(procs.SetCount(info.dwNumberOfProcessors));

ULONG size = info.dwNumberOfProcessors * sizeof(ULONG64);

VERIFY(::QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime(&size,
                                     procs.GetData()));

for (size_t index = 0; index < procs.GetCount(); ++index)
{
    ULONG64 idleCycles = procs[index];
    cout << "Processor " << index << ": " << idleCycles << endl;
}
```

Is it possible to access from my C# project?

Comment: Look up the `PerformanceCounter` class

Comment: PerformanceCounter will only give you values from between the last call to  to get the values right? So if other programs are using it also wouldn't that mess each other's readings up?

Comment: *"Is it possible to access from my C# project?"* - The link you provided points out, that the application calling this code requires .NET 2.0. So presumably that is possible. Anyway, this is a pretty poor question. It asks whether a tiny set of Windows API calls can be used from .NET, instead of asking the generic question: Can I call a native C API from managed .NET code? And the answer is: Yes. P/Invoke is probably the most straight forward way to do so.

Comment: No, each Performance counter object is independent. You could even have 2 in the same program and they would not interfere with each other